# IE 8 support for file upload

Tags: html, file, internet-explorer, file-upload, ie8-compatibility-mode

I’m working on html5 website and I need to support ie8 also. I have problem with uploading photo in IE8 which works fine in IE9+ and other browsers:

My code:

```
var fileInput = $('#uploadMedia');

    var maxSize = imageMaxsize;

    var isVideo = isVideos(fileInput.val());
    var isImage = isImages(fileInput.val());

    if(! isVideo && !isImage ){
        alert("error");
        $.fancybox.open('#uploaded_error');
    }

    if (isVideo)
        var maxSize = videoMaxSize;

    if(fileInput.get(0).files.length || fileInput.get(0).files.length ==null){
            var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
//            alert(fileSize);
            if(fileSize>maxSize){
                //alert("error2");
                $.fancybox.open('#uploaded_error');
                return false;
            }
    }
```

And I'm getting error in line `fileInput.get(0).files.length`

Error:

```
get(...).files.length' is null or not an object
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: IE8 does not support FileList (i.e. fileinput.files) so you wont be able to get the file size.

Comment: HOw we can fix this issue. Quick fix so that it wont effect other browsers